# Need assistance with attributes in Java

Tags: java, string, oop, methods, void

What I'm trying to do is access an object, in this case date1 which has 3 attributes day, month and year. I'm attempting to make a method called showTomorrow() which will display the objects information 1 day infront in String format. This means I cannot alter the attributes of the original object.

I've written the Data.java program and it's shown below, if someone could point me in the right direction or show me what it would be really helpfull.

This is what I'd essentially be running on my main method I believe.

```
**Date date1 = new Date(30, 12, 2013)** // instantiate a new object with those paramaters

**date1.showDate();** // display the original date

**date1.tomorrow();** // shows what that date would be 1 day infront
```

The problem is right now it's not displaying anything. I thought that by saying dayTomorrow = this.day++; I was adding it's default value + 1 day to the variable dayTomorrow.

```
public class Date
{
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private int dayTomorrow;
    private int monthTomorrow;
    private int yearTomorrow;

    public Date()
    {
            day = 1;
            month = 1;
            year = 1970;
    }
    public Date(int inDay, int inMonth, int inYear)
    {
            day = inDay;
            month = inMonth;
            year = inYear;
    }
    public void setDate(int inDay, int inMonth, int inYear)
    {
            day = inDay;
            month = inMonth;
            year = inYear;
    }
    public String getDate()
    {
            String strDate;
            strDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            return strDate;
    }
    public String getTomorrow()
    {
            String strTomorrow;
            strTomorrow = dayTomorrow + "/" + monthTomorrow + "/" + yearTomorrow;
            return strTomorrow;
    }
    public String tomorrow()
    {
            dayTomorrow = this.day++;
            monthTomorrow = this.month;
            yearTomorrow = this.year;

            if(dayTomorrow > 30)
            {
                    dayTomorrow = 1;
                    monthTomorrow = this.month++;
            }
            if(monthTomorrow > 12)
            {
                    monthTomorrow = 1;
                    yearTomorrow = this.year++;
            }

            return getTomorrow();
    }
    public void showDate()
    {
            System.out.print("\n\n THIS OBJECT IS STORING ");
            System.out.print(getDate());
            System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
    public void showTomorrow()
    {
            System.out.print("\n\n THE DATE TOMORROW IS ");
            System.out.print(getTomorrow());
            System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
    public boolean equals(Date inDate)
    {
            if(this.day == inDate.day && this.month == inDate.month && this.year == inDate.year)
            {
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                    return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, every year is a leap year? Don't roll your own code to manipulate dates.

Comment: Are You calling showDate() after date1.tomorrow()?

Comment: I completely agree with @JackManey. Please get a library to handle this. [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) comes highly recommended. The native Java time stuff kind of sucks :(

Comment: I need to do it this way because it's how the work I've been given has been asked to be done.

Comment: @MarioStanicic - Then explain to them why doing it this way is a) a terrible idea, b) much slower to build, test, and use than using a date manipulation library, and c) *will* lead to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `++this.day`, `++this.month` and `++this.year`. When you use `this.day++` it returns the previous date value, not the new. Putting the `++` in the front solves the problem. Also, it changes the `day` value... you might want to change that to `this.day + 1`.

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting any output to begin with. Any ideas where I've made a mistake?

Comment: Other problem is, you are calling ``tomorrow()`` alone. ``tomorrow()`` doesn't print anything. Try to call ``System.out.println(date.tomorrow())``.

Comment: I should point out that the tomorrow() method MUST be a String. I'm not sure if that matters but the error I'm receiving is 
./Date.java:60: 'void' type not allowed here
                System.out.println(showTomorrow());

Comment: `showTomorrow()` doesn't return anything. You are trying to print `void`. Use `System.out.println(date1.tomorrow())` instead, or just `date1.showTomorrow()`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's changing the values for my objects attributes? I'm only trying to display what they would be a day after with tomorrow()

Comment: It is changing the values, because you are using the `++` operator. It changes the attribute value. Change `dayTomorrow = this.day++;` to `dayTomorrow = this.day + 1;`. It will change only the `dayTomorrow` variable, not the `day` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are You calling showDate() after date1.tomorrow() to show your output?

or instead of `date1.tomorrow();` call `date1.showTomorrow();`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

post incremention ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the native date support in java but I figured you are just practicing right?

This should do the trick:

```
public class Date {
    private int day = 1;
    private int month = 1;
    private int year = 1970;
    private int dayTomorrow = day+1;
    private int monthTomorrow;
    private int yearTomorrow;

    public Date()
    {
            tomorrow();
    }
    public Date(int inDay, int inMonth, int inYear)
    {
            day = inDay;
            month = inMonth;
            year = inYear;
            tomorrow();
    }
    public void setDate(int inDay, int inMonth, int inYear)
    {
            day = inDay;
            month = inMonth;
            year = inYear;
    }
    public String getDate()
    {
            String strDate;
            strDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            return strDate;
    }
    public String getTomorrow()
    {
            String strTomorrow;
            strTomorrow = dayTomorrow + "/" + monthTomorrow + "/" + yearTomorrow;
            return strTomorrow;
    }
    public void tomorrow()
    {
            monthTomorrow = this.month;
            yearTomorrow = this.year;

            if(dayTomorrow > 30)
            {
                    dayTomorrow = 1;
                    monthTomorrow = this.month++;
            }
            if(monthTomorrow > 12)
            {
                    monthTomorrow = 1;
                    yearTomorrow = this.year++;
            }
    }
    public void showDate()
    {
            System.out.print("\n\n THIS OBJECT IS STORING ");
            System.out.print(getDate());
            System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
    public void showTomorrow()
    {
            System.out.print("\n\n THE DATE TOMORROW IS ");
            System.out.print(getTomorrow());
            System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
    public boolean equals(Date inDate)
    {
            if(this.day == inDate.day && this.month == inDate.month && this.year == inDate.year)
            {
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                    return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Look carefully for any changes i've made ;)
Here's the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date d = new Date();
    d.showDate();
    d.showTomorrow();
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is I believe he wants us to have tomorrow() also do the displaying in that method itself.

Comment: I've added the public static void main as a reference.
Really? I don't see why, there is a getDate() function...

Comment: If he does want that to happen, he should just add System.out.println(getTomorrow());

Comment: For the time being I'm using void and for some reason my code is changing the objects attributes when all I'm trying to do is display what they would be a day ahead.

Comment: The day attribute is never incremented, the dayTomorrow is incremented only once and the monthTomorrow and dayTomorrow are incremented accordingly at the end of a month. Even after calling the getDate and getTomorrow mutliple times I still get the same result. I don't think I understand what you mean?

Comment: Okay, so, according to this code, what's the day after February 28, 2013?

Comment: That would be February 29 2013... That's just a minor adjustment, at least the code is working now :)